# angular not found in firebug on ubuntu after installing with bower/yeoman

Tags: angularjs

Firebug is giving me the error:
ReferenceError: angular is not defined

I installed everything with yeoman. I am trying to access the site through apache2. Grunt isn't finding Gruntfile.js even though it does exist.

I am on Ubuntu.

Why doesn't yeoman/bower setup everything?

Comment: make sure the angular.js is actually present and gets loaded BEFORE you start to access any angular.module or something alike.

Comment: I had to move the bower_components dir down one level to the app dir. For some reason, bower was installing bower_components above the app dir. And the js includes look for bower_components on the same level as their dir (app). I don't know how that works for grunt but that default bower dir layout doesn't work for apache2.

Answer (score 2):

Possible causes may be permission issues. If you are on ubuntu and trying bower command with sudo permission,ie: "sudo bower install", you need to explicitly add --allow-root flag , So bower could have write permission in bower_components directory. For allowing root install , Try below command.

```
sudo bower --allow-root install
```

Also You should check your html source code whether it is including angularjs library!

Comment: What does --allow-root do?

Comment: If you are on ubuntu and trying bower command with sudo permission,ie: "sudo bower install", you need to explicitly add --allow-root flag , So bower could have write permission in bower_components directory.

Comment: Wow. I would have assumed bower was smart enough when you ran it with sudo. I had to move bower_components down one level. Bower puts bower_components above the web directory so it wasn't being included.